# Weird object rotation problem

Tags: objects

**Hi**, I'm new to blender, and i'm confused right now.

I have a free car model from net, and I want to rotate it's wheel. But the rotating is weird.

*When I click on the wheel:*
[image: When I click on the wheel]

*When I start rotating:*
[image: When I start rotating]

Comment: The Pivot Point of rotations and scales is vital. It looks to be set to '3D cursor', so rotations will be around that. Change the Pivot (In the header, next to the 'Orientation') or move / snap the cursor to your desired center.

Comment: Thanks, it working!

Comment: @RobinBetts: you should write it as answer ;) So you will get score and other people don't check this question again because they think there is no answer ;) like me :( and of course because you were the first and of course right! ;)

Comment: @Chris Guilty. We should never answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to fix this select the object that is acting weird and Right Click then go to Set Origin > Origin to Geometry. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

The Pivot Point of rotations and scales is vital.

Yours looks to be set to '3D cursor', so rotations will be around that. Change the Pivot (In the header, next to the 'Transform Orientation'), or move / snap the 3D cursor to your desired center.